# MVC3 StorageSessionStateProvider - Do I need it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

I notice in the azure examples they are using:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="TableStorageSessionStateProvider">
```

Can someone explain what this is used for with MVC3? I'm very confused about session state. Do I really need to use it if my application does not have anything like a shopping cart? Is it needed if I just want to do simple authentication? I removed the code from my web.config and my authentication still seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're publishing your application to Azure and you're using Session in any way (this includes MVC's TempData) then you will probably need to use some kind of central storage for session, rather than using the default "InProc" provider which just stores the user's session in the application's own memory. With azure, you can use, among others, SQL Azure or the AppFabric Cache (still in CTP).

Here is a good lab for AppFabric:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg457897

And here's one for SQL Azure (not supported): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/08/04/10046103.aspx

This is because you could have mutiple instances running or you instance could be moved at any given moment.

It sounds like your application doesn't currently use Session State so you won't need to worry about it. (although, remember that the TempData dictionary uses Session under the hood)

Comment: Indeed, if using MVC you don't need to worry about the session state. Problems appear when using ASP.NET sessions state.

Comment: @Tudor - I'm not sure this is the case - TempData is a common item in MVC and with the PRG pattern recommended - its a great way for passing info and status messages. Since TempData relies in asp.net session state, you then have an issue.